# Adding kunena forum to joomla website

Tags: joomla-3.x, kunena

I am currently building my first serious joomla website and i am trying to add the
kunena forum. I have read every possibol guide and followed them, but i do not succeed to see the forum on the website.
I made sure it's published and not hidden practically everywhere, and i do not know what to do.
My current template is xeon if that matters
(link: http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=xeon)

Comment: Have you created a menu item and set it to view the forum?

Answer (score 2):

When you install Kunena, it creates "Kunena Menu". This menu has several items to navigate the forum following the most common practice.

To publish it, you can publish this menu with a new menu module instance, on a template specific position. Or, you can create a new "alias" menu item in your "Main Menu", targeting "Kunena Menu"/"Forum" menu item.